# Websocket Apache 2.4.x Proxy Tomcat 7.x open event happens only on browser side

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, websocket, java-websocket

I programmed a chat app using javascript on browser side and server
endpoint programmed with javax.websocket api. I first tested the app
by establishing connection between browser and tomcat and everything
worked fine (OS is Windows 7).

When I tried to use a apache 2.4.18 server as a proxy reverse over ssl it seems that the connection gets not completely established and I only get an `onopen` event on the browser.
My tomcat log tells me, that the server endpoint instance also is created, but the `onopen` event doesn't happen on the server endpoint instance. It seems to me that the server endpoint listens on the wrong port or something like this.

I use an ajp connector on the tomcat side. I tried to solve the problem or get an idea where it could fail, but with no success.

Here are my code snippets:

## Chrome-Network-Log:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaMhd.png)

## Chrome-Javascript-console:

```
controller_chat.js:1952 chatBuildWSLink
controller_chat.js:1960 wsLink: wss://x:443/myapp/chat
controller_chat.js:343 chatCheckConnection
controller_chat.js:345 connect
controller_chat.js:313 Connecting to wss://x:443/myapp/chat
controller_chat.js:353 wsServerOnOpen
controller_chat.js:363 wsServerOnMessage
controller_chat.js:411 wsServerOnError
controller_chat.js:422 wsServerOnClose
controller_chat.js:228 chatCreateMenuBar
controller_chat.js:5 chatCreateTable
controller_chat.js:5 chatCreateTable
controller_chat.js:5 chatCreateTable
controller_chat.js:5 chatCreateTable
controller_chat.js:355 onopen Event: {"isTrusted":true}
controller_chat.js:356 onopen Event-Code: undefined
controller_chat.js:357 onopen Event-Reason: undefined
controller_chat.js:358 onopen Event-WasClean: undefined
```

## My apache httpd-conf:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so                            
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

ProxyPass /myapp/chat/ wss://x:443/myapp/chat 
ProxyPassReverse /myapp/chat/ wss://x:443/myapp/chat 

ProxyPass /myapp/ ajp://x:8009/myapp/
ProxyPassReverse /eProjectCare/ ajp://x:8009/myapp/

NameVirtualHost myhost
<VirtualHost myhost:443>

  ...
  DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"
  ServerName myhost
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "c:/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/chat.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/chat.key"

...
</VirtualHost>

KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 1000
```

## My Tomcat-Log:

```
09:39:50.756 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) ChatServer.checkOrigin , originHeaderValue: https://myhost
09:39:50.756 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) ChatServer.checkOrigin checkOrigin: true
09:39:50.756 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) ChatServer.getNegotiatedSubprotocol , getNegotiatedSubprotocol: 
09:39:50.756 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) ChatServer.getNegotiatedSubprotocol, negotiated Subprotocoll:  
09:39:50.756 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) ChatServer.getNegotiatedExtensions , getNegotiatedExtensions: 
09:39:50.756 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) ChatServer.getNegotiatedExtensions, negotiatedExtensions: permessage-deflate
09:39:50.756 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) ChatServer.getNegotiatedExtensions NegotiatedExtensions: [org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsExtension@28130514]
09:39:50.756 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) ChatServer.modifyHandshake , modifyHandshake: 
09:39:50.756 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) ChatServer.modifyHandshake , HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@3fbf9eec
09:39:50.756 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) ChatServer.modifyHandshake , csrfsession: 5e7f914546aef5bf389472c86b67234c1e68dc1e
09:39:50.756 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) ChatServer.modifyHandshake , csrfrequest: 
09:39:50.758 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) SecurityService.readUser: Benutzer 3 wird aus der Datenbank gelesen ...
09:39:50.759 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) DatabaseService.closeConnection: schliesse Connection fuer: <.getLiveUser:> (1137989066)
09:39:50.759 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) ChatServer.modifyHandshake , userProperties for ServerEndpointConfig set...: {}
09:39:50.759 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) ChatServer.getEndpointInstance , getEndpointInstance: 
09:39:50.759 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) ChatServer Erstelle Endpoint-Instanz!
09:39:50.759 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] DEBUG admin (3/1) ChatServer.getEndpointInstance Endpoint-Instance: de.pmgnet.eprojectcare.websocket.chat.chatserver.ChatServer@3f39a0a
```

Normally after that, the onopen event happens in my server-endpoint.class and gets logged, but this only happens if I establish the connection without proxy to tomcat...

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so please be patient with me, if I forgot some important information in my subscription. Would
be nice if anyone has a suggestion. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for all that maybe struggle with the same topic, 
after a lot of fetching through websites and reading, i found a solution and will make a conclusion for all that are interested.

> ## AJP-Connector:
>
> AJP - connector of tomcat 7 does not! support websocket but it also
>   does not give any logs or errors, see also this:
>   [1](http://www.silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2009/3/31/Enabling-SSL-on-Apache-on-Windows):
>   https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201408.mbo
>   x/%3C53FF3A3A.3040507@christopherschultz.net%3E

So for websocket i used the https - connector, that already comes with the server.xml of apache tomcat:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https"      secure="true"
               keystoreFile="E:\ssl\mykeystore" keystorePass="315225"    keyPass="315225"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

> I defined a selfsigned certificate regarding to the article of bob: [enter link description here](http://www.silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2009/3/31/Enabling-SSL-on-Apache-on-Windows)

## > httdp.conf

I changed the ports in the httpd.conf to fit with the proxypass:

```
ProxyPass /myapp/chat wss://myhost:8443/myapp/chat
ProxyPassReverse /myapp/chat wss://myhost:8443/myapp/chat

ProxyPass /myapp/ https://myhost:8443/myapp/
ProxyPassReverse /myapp/ https://myhost:8443/myapp/
```

> Well, this was ending in an Proxy-Error caused by the
>   self-signed-certificate of the tomcat. For testing and development you
>   can avoid this with a few additional rows in the httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none 
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
</IfModule>
```

The last thing for me to solve, was to choose the right dependency in my pom.xml for the websocket, depending on the tomcat-version, it can be found on maven-repository: [enter link description here](http://mvnrepository.com/) and should look like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.64</version>
</dependency>
```

> Don't use the javax.websocket dependency, even with the
>   `<scope>provided</scope>` attribute it didn't work for me (maybe i did
>   something wrong or forgot something)
>
> Hope this works and helps you guys:-)

Answer (score 0):

add / to the end of the wss in your proxy setting

```
ProxyPass /myapp/chat/ wss://x:443/myapp/chat/
ProxyPassReverse /myapp/chat/ wss://x:443/myapp/chat/
```